# How to hide the dialog when user touches the screen (outside)?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

where should I implement `dialog.hide` to hide my dialog when the user touches the screen in libgdx, I mean outside the borders of the dialog.

I'm looking for something similar to the following in Android SDK.

`dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stage has the size of your screen, so, you can add input listener on stage

```
stage.addListener(new InputListener(){
     @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //you action here
            stage.removeActor(dialog);
            return true;
        }

});
```

dialog must be the field of your class, of course

Comment: `stage.removeActor` does not exist

Comment: Yes, it is my mistake. Dialog does not belong to this stage. Change `stage.removeActor` with `dialog.hide()`

Comment: That's one way to do it and it works, downside is it closes the dialog on touch, even if the touch is within the border of the dialog, isn't there a better option which closes the dialog only if the user touches somewhere outside the borders of a dialog?

Comment: You can override `touchDown` and `touchUp` methods on dialog and set to do nothing there